# Google Dialogflow does not install for .net v4.6 from nuget

Tags: c#, nuget, dialogflow-es, .net-4.6

I am trying to install Google DialogFlow from nuget in .net v4.6. But it does not install. And I have to use .net v4.6 coz I have an integration with workflow foundation.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error     Could not install package 'Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2 3.0.0'.
> You are trying to install this package into a project that targets
> '.NETFramework, Version=v4.6', but the package does not contain any
> assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
> framework. For more information, contact the package author.

What fixes can I try?

Comment: Is this really problematic to migrate upper versions of .NET ?

Comment: Could you use .NETFramework 4.6.1?

Comment: @kanils_ no, I could not do that coz I have dependency.

Comment: There is a link where writes that Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2 v3.0.0 supports on .NETFramework 4.6.1 .
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2/#:~:text=Versions-,.NETFramework%204.6.1,-Google.Api.Gax

Comment: Were you able to to install Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2 v3 as mentioned in this [documentation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2/#:~:text=Versions-,.NETFramework%204.6.1,-Google.Api.Gax)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @kanlis_, for .NETFramework 4.6.1 use the Google DialogFlow package version 3.8.0 as mentioned [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2/#:%7E:text=Versions-,.NETFramework%204.6.1,-Google.Api.Gax).